# Efficient structure for querying membership in many-to-many relationship where tableA has ONLY the indicated members from tableB?

Tags: postgresql, join

I'm working on an application with a PostgreSQL back end. There is a many-to-many relationship between `items` in one table and `tags` in another table. The specs require that the application be able to respond to frequent queries that provide a list of `tags` as parameters and expect in response a list of all `items` which contain *only* those `tags` but not necessarily *all* of those tags.

Is there an efficient (non-exponential complexity) way to structure my database (or application) to suit this task? At launch, I shall have on the order of 12K `items` and 1K `tags`.

E.g.
A user requests a list of all `items` for tags `a`, `b`, and `c`.
The response contains items with the following tag sets:

```
{}
{a}
{a,b,c}
```

The response must *not* contain items with the following tag sets:

```
{d}
{a,b,c,d}
```

The structure of `tags` table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    description text,
    revision_id integer
);
```

Comment: Please show us the `create table` statement for the `tags` table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, here's the `create table` statement: http://pastebin.com/ufSzQAMM